# Why put synchronous state in redux store?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, single-page-application, flux

What's the point of putting non async state in redux store? For example you have a modal, show or no show, you want to write so much to just to toggle? What's wrong with just putting it as local state in react component, and use setState to update it?

My rule of thumb of deciding which state should go through redux is that the data is async, otherwise there will so many ui states in the store and it will become so big one day, what's your thought?

Comment: async data can also be in a local state, then why async data should be in redux store?

Comment: @Sagivb.g that's the point of using redux, performances and consistency.

Comment: I was just trying to make a point, `redux` is not at all about async data or sync data state.

Comment: @Sagivb.g so are you putting all states in redux store? give me real examples so that I can relate better.

Comment: mark's answer nails it.

Comment: example: a menu with a dark theme toggle button. where should the `isChecked` get stored? the entire app needs to know if the dark theme is activated.

Comment: I see, seems like I'm mixing local react state with redux lol.

Comment: As some mentioned, it is absolutely fine to keep local (component) state sometimes. for example a `<select/>` component that keep tracks if its extended or collapsed (again, until other parts of the app needs to know about it).

Answer (score 5):

I'll quote the "rules of thumb for when to put data in Redux" from [the Redux FAQ entry on Redux state vs component state](https://redux.js.org/faq/organizingstate#do-i-have-to-put-all-my-state-into-redux-should-i-ever-use-reacts-setstate):

> Some common rules of thumb for determining what kind of data should be put into Redux:
>
> - Do other parts of the application care about this data?
> - Do you need to be able to create further derived data based on this original data?
> - Is the same data being used to drive multiple components?
> - Is there value to you in being able to restore this state to a given point in time (ie, time travel debugging)?
> - Do you want to cache the data (ie, use what's in state if it's already there instead of re-requesting it)?

It's perfectly valid to want to keep UI state in Redux.  In fact, [I wrote an entire blog post demonstrating ways to store UI state like modals and toasts in Redux](https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2017/07/practical-redux-part-10-managing-modals/).

Comment: I would add that if you are already using `redux` as state manager, then local state should be only for **local** data, that only the same component "cares" about it. (though the first bullet in your answer kinda address this) :)

Comment: so you're saying toggle a text I should write bunch of boiletplate of redux just to do a show/hide?

Comment: Does any other component care about this `isToggled` state?

Comment: @Sagivb.g obviously no, most of the ui state doesn't care about other component, for example, you have a container for login page, there's 2 fields, username and password, why would you put the states of the inputs into redux store? Just use the setState. Am I right?

Comment: mark stated 5 key question that you can ask yourself on weather to store the data in `redux` or local. i advice to follow them.

Comment: @Sagivb.g my problem is I follow tutorials for beginner, any recommendation to become better at redux?

Comment: @AlisaTMorgan I think the documentation of `redux` are great. with that said, i know that @markerikson (co author of `redux` and the one posted this answer) is working in improving them as we speak.

Comment: oh and i almost forgot, you should defiantly watch [getting started with redux](https://egghead.io/courses/getting-started-with-redux) by Dan abramov (also one of redux authors).

Comment: @AlisaTMorgan : Please see  [my suggested resources for getting started with Redux](http://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2017/12/blogged-answers-learn-redux/), [the slides from my Redux workshop](https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2018/06/redux-fundamentals-workshop-slides/), and the [Redux docs in general](https://redux.js.org).  We also have a [Learning Resources page in our docs](https://redux.js.org/introduction/learningresources) that points to more recommended articles.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong with using local component state and redux state all in the same app. Note that `setState()` is still asynchronous.

Answer (score 1):

Some components want to have access to the same data. This data can be either synchronous or asynchronously obtain which doesn't really matter. The following image will describe this clearer:

[image]
([source: https://www.foreach.be](https://www.foreach.be/blog/why-the-react-redux-combo-works-like-magic))

When components which are relatively far each other, like the left and right branch of components in the picture, they can use the store for general access. Therefore, the redux store not only supplies a method to deal with async data, it also is very useful to  conveniently get the data to every component in the react app. Regardless of the location of the component you can give it access to the store.

Comment: any code example? how can a deeply nested chilren get state from store? `mapStateToProps`? and access it using `this.props.something`?